# Jest mock for clone function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a fetch request and I've never been able to parse the json from the response without cloning the response: `response.clone().json()` for context:

```js
fetch(url) {
   .then((response) => { 
     response.clone().json()
   })
   .((json) => {
     //updates a state from `useState`
     setResponse(json)
   })
```

I'm 100% new to testing with Jest and testing-library but so far I've set a mock for the fetch function:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const mockedData = jest.fn(() => [{test: "title"}]);
  global.fetch = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue((mockedData) =>
  Promise.resolve({
      json: () => Promise.resolve(JSON.stringify(mockedData))
  })
  )
}, []);
```

The test is failing saying: `error fetching response: TypeError: response.clone is not a function`.
If I remove the mock for `global.fetch` I get: `ReferenceError: fetch is not defined`.  So it seems like I need to mock all these functions out?

Short of knowing how I can fix that issue with `clone` I'd be curious if there is another way I can fetch this data without cloning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that you would need to mock all subfunctions, also clone.

But you are also correct that you should not need to clone the data from fetch. Your syntax seems to be a little bit off, and you are not returning the json from your function.

Try this

```
fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => {
        //updates a state from `useState`
        setResponse(json);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks.  I don't really understand how the syntax was off other than removing the clone function?  Can you explain that a bit?

Comment: First: `.then((response) => { response.clone().json() })` dont actually return any data. You just call the function to parse to json, but you dont return the data and pass it to the next chain. The correct would be `.then((response) => { return response.clone().json()  })`. In my answer I used a short form for returning from the function by removing the brackets around, this creates a automagic return `.then((response) => response.clone().json() )` and can only be used when you have one line of code.
Second you had a syntax error in your second chaining. Im pretty sure the code would crash?